# Apple's PDFKit: Free draw with Ink annotation

Tags: ios, annotations, pdfkit

I just want to draw on a PDF file using PDFKit. This sounds simple but I'm having a lot of trouble. From the documentation, the ink annotations seem to be appropriate for this. Here's my code:

```
/// Adds a new annotation
func addAnnotation(color: UIColor, point: CGPoint) {
    currentPage = pdfView.page(for: point, nearest: false)

    // Here I convert the coordinates to the document and create a new annotation
    if currentPage != nil {
        let topRight = pdfView.convert(pdfView.frame.topRightCorner, to: currentPage!)
        newAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: topRight.x, height: topRight.y)), forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
        newAnnotation!.color = color
        currentPage!.addAnnotation(newAnnotation!)
    }
    else {
        newAnnotation = PDFAnnotation()
    }
}

/// Adds a new path, maybe a new annotation
func addPath(color: UIColor, point: CGPoint, lineWidth: CGFloat) {

    // Create annotation
    if newAnnotation == nil {
        addAnnotation(color: color, point: point)
    }

    guard currentPage != nil else { return }

    let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(point, to: currentPage!)

    // Create initial path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 200
    path.move(to: convertedPoint)
    path.addLine(to: convertedPoint)
    newAnnotation!.add(path)
}

/// Updates the last drawn annotation
func updatePath(point: CGPoint) {
    if let annotation = newAnnotation, let page = currentPage {
        let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(point, to: page)
        let lastPath = annotation.paths!.last!
        lastPath.addLine(to: convertedPoint)
        annotation.remove(lastPath)
        annotation.add(lastPath)
    }
}
```

My main problem is performance. I wrote all this code just to have a functional drawing program. What I understood in the process:

- Grouping the paths in the annotations instead of having one annotation per path seems to be more efficient. So I added the addAnnotation() method, which sometimes creates a new annotation.
- The 'bounds' property when creating an annotation plays a big part in performance. Setting this property to the page's bounds makes the program very slow.But the thing is, I don't know the bounds of the annotation before the user finish drawing...
- I have a method touchMoved(), where I want to add a point the path. At first, I was just doing:

  ```
  if let annotation = newAnnotation, let page = currentPage {
      let convertedPoint = pdfView.convert(point, to: page)
      let lastPath = annotation.paths!.last!
      lastPath.addLine(to: convertedPoint)
  }
  ```

but the path was not updating, so I added the lines:

```
    annotation.remove(lastPath)
    annotation.add(lastPath)
```

This turned out to be really bad in term of performances (the path sometimes disappear, and reappear later).

I'm assuming there's a better way to do all of this, but I can't find any good example. If you have a working example of Ink annotations on PDFKit, that would be also great.

Side question: in my code I set the bezierPath's lineWidth to 200. This is because I want to change the lineWidth of the annotation, but changing the bezierPath's lineWidth doesn't seem to change anything. Any idea on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My observations are simiar to yours. I found that manipulating PDFAnnotation is troublesome, mostly because of a bug ([PDFAnnotation with PDFAnnotationSubtype equal to .widget is not refreshing its appearance after adding it to PDFPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815383/pdfannotation-with-pdfannotationsubtype-equal-to-widget-is-not-refreshing-its-a)).
Trick with deleting and readding them to `PDFView` is a nasty workaround.

Maybe it would be better to try with different approach? 
For example:

1. Draw on a (transparent) `CGLayer` using `CoreGraphics`, on the top of PDFView.
2. Transform drawing layer to `UIImage`.
3. Add annotation with image to your `PDFView`. You can check Apple samples to find out how to do it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004035

Comment: This seems to be a good workaround, I'm gonna look into that.

Comment: This is indeed working. Do you have any idea for the lineWidth problem though ? This is even more important with this solution: I'm drawing on a layer with a certain width, but when I add it at the end as an annotation, the drawing always have a width of 1, and I can't change it. How can I change the width of the annotation, and is there any way I can convert the width in Core Graphics to the document, so that the drawing look the same when it's added ? Thanks

Comment: I didn't found any issues with annotation width. If you don't mind please add separate question for it. Source code would be also very helpful.